# Django Model Foreign Key Casting Integer to Char

Tags: python, django

Edited
I have two tables Table1 and Table2. Table1 has a field x of type int and Table2 has primary key y of type char. I am trying to do x = models.ForeignKey(Table2, ...) but it tries to cast y to an int first. In doing so, this overflows the int. I am wondering if it is possible to first cast x to a char and then do the foreign key relationship.

Comment: Please provide an example, it makes your question more reader-friendly :)

Comment: ForeignKey is used to relate one model to another. Not fields. Show us more. Not sure what you are trying to do as @Impulse says